# Preventing repeated execution of operations in Laravel Controller Function

Tags: database, laravel, controller

I want to prevent repeated actions of users, e.g. A user can perform an action only once. The problem is that when the user double clicks the link of the request, the action is performed twice.

The analogy of the requested function as following:

```
public function someAction($id) {
    ...
    $user = User::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)                                   
                        ->lockForUpdate()
                        ->first();

    if($user->isActionPerformed == False) {

        // perform the action here.
        $user->isActionPerformed = True;
        $user->save();
        return View::make();

    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I expect the second request to wait the db reply which is locked by the first request. When the db reply comes, $user->isActionPerformed would be True. So that, the second request would be returned by 0.

How can I prevent repeated actions?

Comment: It would be much easier and more practical to restrict those kind of actions on the client side, rather than check state on the server side. Just detect and ignore double clicks in the browser.

Comment: I would prevent it also on the client side, but I wonder if some attackers can call the function repeatedly in a mallicious manner.

Comment: That is also not something which you should be managing in your application. For example a very simple approach would be to limit the number of requests per second that the HTTP server accepts for that specific route URL.

Comment: Isn't the general logic to assume the client won't behave correctly, and use business logic to ensure a proper result. This lock concept seems reasonable.